# Call ng-click function from ng-change function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in angularjs and please clear me if I'm wrong.

Im using single select and want to fetch the value and based on value I want to perform action. Eg: If I will get "DELETE" then I want to send it to ng-click function with name delete. Below is my code :-

**html.jsp**

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<select ng-model="some_action.type"  ng-change="actionchange(some_action.type)" ng-options="type.value as type.displayName for type in types">
</select>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
    function AppCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.some_action={
            type: 'Select'
        }

        $scope.types = [
            {value: 'DELETE', displayName: 'Delete'},
            {value: 'SUSPEND', displayName: 'Suspend'}
         ]
    }

$scope.actionchange= function(value) {
     console.log('change action is -'+ value);
     //here I will fetch some ids which will sent to some other's click function
};
```

So i'm using ng-click function for both action seperately and want to be use from ng-change which will call ng-click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function AppCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.some_action = {
            type: 'Select'
        }

        $scope.types = [{
                value: 'DELETE',
                displayName: 'Delete'
            },
            {
                value: 'SUSPEND',
                displayName: 'Suspend'
            }
        ]
    }

    $scope.actionchange = function(value) {
        console.log('change action is -' + value);
        var fetchIds= [];
        // based on the condition push all ids to fetchIDS

        $scope.method_Delete(fetchIds);
    };

$scope.method_Delete=function(fetchIds){
// do something using fetchIds
}
```